# Create chart from DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, charts

I have a form with `DataGridView` (2 columns: `PartnerName`, `Adult`)

[image]

Please, I need to fill data from `DataGridView` to chart and print the chart

Comment: i didn't know how to try with charts but i fill dataGridView by:
 this.all_Booking_DataTableAdapter.Fill(this.partners_DataSet.All_Booking_Data);

Comment: There is no `dataGridView` in the code you posted. Find where you set `dataGridView.DataSource` property and do the same for the `Chart`.

Comment: This line of code loads data form StoredProcedure into the 'partners_DataSet.All_Booking_Data'
this.all_Booking_DataTableAdapter.Fill(this.partners_DataSet.All_Booking_Data);

Comment: Why are you posted the same code twice? See my comment above again.

Comment: ok  Dmitry it's done thank you

Comment: With a little luck you can use the same datasource for both; if not you'll have to extract and prepare the data from the dgv's datasource and create a suitable datasource for the chart. of course you could loop through the rows and add data points for each, but that would be rather crude.. although it may be a start to get a feeling for the chart control..

Answer (score 3):

You can get idea from following code:

```
private void DataGridBinding_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   // Populate series data using random data
  double[]    yValues = { 23.67, 75.45, 60.45, 34.54, 85.62, 32.43, 55.98, 67.23 };
  for(int pointIndex = 0; pointIndex < yValues.Length; pointIndex++)
  {
    chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(1990 + pointIndex, yValues[pointIndex]);
  }

  // Export series values into DataSet object
  dataSet1 = chart1.DataManipulator.ExportSeriesValues("Series1");

  // Data bind DataGrid control. 
  SeriesValuesDataGrid.DataSource = dataSet1;

  // Set Series name for data
  SeriesValuesDataGrid.DataMember = "Series1";

}

private void SeriesValuesDataGrid_CurrentCellChanged(object sender,System.EventArgs e)
{
   // Initializes a new instance of the DataView class
   DataView firstView = new DataView(dataSet1.Tables[0]);

   // Since the DataView implements IEnumerable, pass the reader directly into
   // the DataBind method with the name of the Columns selected in the query    
   chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBindXY(firstView,"X",firstView,"Y");

   // Invalidate Chart
   chart1.Invalidate();
}
```

[image]

You can get complete project code from [Samples Environments for Microsoft Chart Controls](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Samples-Environments-for-b01e9c61)
and find the code from WorkingWithData>DataManipulation>Exporting>DataGridBinding section.